# Initialize an ArrayList of Class from An ArrayList of Names

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a Student App. The user gives the number of students and then he will add the List of names of his students that will be stored in an `ArrayList<String>`.

```
ArrayList<String> Names= new ArrayList<String>();
```

After getting the names, I want to add them to the Student Class.

```
public Class Student{
    private String Name;
    private ArrayList<Double> Grade=new ArrayList<Double>();
    public Student(String name){Name=name;}
    ....
}
```

To do that I have made a Student type `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Student> Students= new ArrayList<Student>();
```

What I want to do is the following but can't figure it out

```
Student (Retreive the first Name from ArrayList Names) = new Student(Also do the Same);
```

I want to do it for every `Student` entered, I was also wondering how to add the List of grades for each `Student`.

Comment: Please don't name variables with starting upper case letters, the java convention is variables start with lower cases (except final static.....)

Comment: I think you will need a HashhMap for this. A Hashhmap of studentname,studentGrade would be a better option.

Comment: What you want to do won't compile and doesn't make any sense.. Can you elaborate more on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList is a dynamic array, just append elements to it if you want to insert them in sequential order.

```
students.add(new Student(myName));
```

To retrieve element by index you can use [`ArrayList.get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) method.

You should avoid inserting element in non sequential order, as it is much less efficient, but it can be done using [`ArrayList.add(index,element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String name: Names)
   Students.add(new Student(name));
```

Comment: This won't compile.. `Names` is a `String`!

Comment: @MarounMaroun: `ArrayList<String> Names= new ArrayList<String>();` Please open your eyes before commenting.

Comment: `private String Name;` - That's what I saw first, sorry -1 --> +1 :)